# Console logging without dev tools

Tags: browser, console, console.log, cefsharp

I am writing an app for the [CefSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/57.0.0) browser which doesn't have anything like Google Chrome Dev Tools.

I need to be able to see console logs in the window somehow.

I am looking for a logging tool that logs `console.log`s to the window so that I can see logs without using any kind of dev tools.

Does a package like this exist?

Comment: What do you mean by `browser which doesn't have anything like Google Chrome Dev Tools.`? `CefSharp` has `DevTools`. for console messages see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_ConsoleMessage.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks but how can I use this? I am not using C# or C++ at all, just running a JS app inside CefSharp on a terminal

Comment: What do you mean? `CefSharp` isn't a standalone browser, it's a framework for integrating a browser into your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your log in `debug.log` under your main path(if you didn't set a path).

If you run `console.log("Hello")` in your `*.js`, you can see it in `debug.log`.